# Why img tag src attribute is empty when run Jest test?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

The image successfully rendered when started the local env but when I run the test the src is always empty.

Already tried it with `:src="require('...')"` but it didn't help.

What config or other thing I miss?

Here are my related configs, files and versions:

```
//package.json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.31"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.69.1"
  }
...
}
```

```
//jest.config.js
{
...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/"
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
  },
}
```

```
//Image.Vue

<template>
  <img src="@/assets/foo.jpg" alt="">
</template>
...
```

```
//image.test.js
...
import MyImg from '../src/components/MyImg.vue'
test('img src attribute is', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyImg)   
  expect(wrapper.find("img").attributes("src")).toBe("/img/foo.jpg")
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out:

The problem is with `jest-transform-stub` as it just adds an empty string to the src attribute.

The solution comes from [https://jestjs.io/docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation#transforming-images-to-their-path):

Create a `fileTransformer.js` file with the following code:

```
//fileTransformer.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, _config, _options) {
    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename))};`;
  },
};
```

and modify Jest config with it:

```
//jest.config.js

...
  transform: {
    //other configs you have
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "<rootDir>/path_to_file/fileTransformer.js",
  },
...
```

and after this the expected `.toBe` value will be: `foo.jpg`

Comment: in my setup (vue3/ts & programmatic alias directives) i had to add the `.default` to `modules.exports` as the vue component under test would never return a value for `src`. 

after debugging the jest source i eventually got into the compiled/transpiled js of the vue component and saw that the `src` attribute was accessing `.default`: `require("@assets/some/key.svg).default`

Comment: eventually figured out i could remove the `.default` behavior in vue3/jest 27. it was to directly require the src file (which is also aliased in vue.config.js) like `:src="require('@assets/somepath/etc.svg')"` and then moving back to the jest 27 asset transformer object result: https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/code-transformation#typescript-with-type-checking